# Можно ли как-то из HashSet<T> получить ссылку на актуальный элемент?

Tags: c#, .net

Ну скажем, что есть класс:

Person, который содержит ID и FIO.

Там переопределен метод `Equals` и `GetHashCode` так, что он для определения уникальности сравнивает ID.

Допустим, я буду хранить все это в `HashSet`. Однако, как мне при необходимости быстро получить актуальный элемент из своей коллекции?

В свежую версию Framework добавлен метод `TryGetValue`. Получается, что я могу только перебором получить?

Словарь мне кажется, что использовать-это излишне`Dictionary<Person,Person>`...

**UPD**

Мотивация у меня в том, что зачем мне использовать `Dictionary`, если сам элемент может являться ключем => при создании `HashSet` я могу передать кастомный сравнитель, который например будет поддерживать уникальность по ID, а затем мне хотелось бы получать актуальное значение из хеша через `Hash.TryGetValue(new Person(){ID=100500})`

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Если получить экземпляр по id, то обычно делают словарь Dictionary<ID, Person>. Переопределять Equals и GetHashCode у Person немного странно...

Comment: Я тоже не понял что должно получится как результат

Comment: У нас в проекте для аналогичной цели используется `Dictionary<IdType, Person>`. А что делать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP , ну мне кажется, что использовать Dictionary несколько излишне, например по тому, что одну и туже персону можно будет добавить с разными id. А так переопределил методы сравнения, кидаешь объекты в хеш-сет и не паришься. Вот только проблема с тем, что бы получить...

Comment: Ну + итоговый занимаемый объём памяти не будет ли выше чем у хеш-сета?

Comment: @Andrew в результате я могу создать интересующий себя объект только с id. Так как я переопределил методы сравнения в классе, то вызов метода contains скажет, что объект есть во множестве. Так вот, я его хочу получить объект находящийся во множестве без перебора коллекции. Или хеш-сет реализован так, что хеши он хронист в стороне от объектов, которые в нем содержатся?

Comment: Конечно, хеши хранятся отдельно. Объем памяти тут не то, на что стоит смотреть, если перерасход и есть, он не значителен. Ну и со словарем тоже можно пользоваться `Contains`: `dict.ContainsKey(perdin.ID)` или через `TryGetValue`. *например по тому, что одну и туже персону можно будет добавить с разными id* - ваше решение ничем не лучше, т.к. *Там переопределен метод Equals и GetHashCode так, что он для определения уникальности сравнивает ID.*

Comment: @АндрейNOP, хм... Ну тогда понятно. Правда, как я понимаю, в смежем фреймворке майки все таки связали хеши с конкретным элементом, так как там добавился метод с возможностью получения значения.

Comment: Этот метод всегда был у того же словаря, просто добавили то что должно быть, как и конструктор с `capacity`, на внутреннее устройство это никак не повлияло. Хранится хеш и ссылка на объект

Comment: А в чем проблема при использовании TryGetValue у HashSet? Она же по сути возвращает через out нужное значение.

Comment: @John- последняя версия фраймворка, что нежелательно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, если верить исходникам, то хеши хранятся не отдельно, а в некой структуре Slot https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,0e4026fbc70ce075 . Slot-это хеш-код элемента и сам элемент.

Comment: Вы можете взять исходник последней версии Hashset и использовать его в своем проекте вместо коллекции из BCL

Comment: Ну, в структуре, отдельно объект и его хеш, я не понимаю к чему вы клоните

Comment: Вообще, тот факт, что вы хотите получить из HashSet объект, у которого HashCode будет совпадать с искомым - бессмысленен. Даже более того, при поиске проверяется не только HashCode, но и равенство двух элементов, через Equal. По своему смыслу у каждого неодинакового объекта должен быть свой HashCode и я уж молчу, что они должны не совпадать при Equal. То есть тот самый объект, который вы ищите - это и есть объект из HashSet по логике HashSet. А то, что у ссылочных элементов могут совпадать всё поля и при этом иметь разные ссылки - уже ваша проблема. Вообще HashSet явно не для этого создавался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала определимся, что [HashSet](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) - это множество уникальных элементов, которое позволяет быстро выполнить проверку наличия конкретного элемента во множестве, но никак не поиск этого элемента по какому то признаку. Также упомяну, что все элементы, что вы добавляете в HashSet должны быть неизменяемыми с корректной имплементацией Equals и GetHashCode. Например, вот некорректная:

```
public class Person
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public override int GetHashCode()=>ID.GetHashCode();
}
```

С такой имплементацией, когда можно изменить хешкод объекта, вот этот код сработает неверно

```
var set = new HashSet<Person>();
var person = new Person() {ID = 10};  
set.Add(person);  
Console.WriteLine(set.Contains(person));  // true
person.ID = 20; 
Console.WriteLine(set.Contains(person));  // false
```

Далее, если вам надо найти какой то объект, то это уже должна быть структура поиска. Например, если вы хотите искать объект по ключу, то вам нужна структура с ассоциацией ключ-объект (ассоциативный массив), чем и является [хеш таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) или словарь.

То есть , если задача в проверке на уникальность элемента во множестве - HashSet, в поиске элемента во множестве - словарь/хеш талица.